# Xamarin.iOS - XCode 5 Provisioning

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xcode5

We are working on an app for a large customer that can only give us a p12 certificate and a provisioning profile (for security reasons), and no access to iTunes Connect or their developer center.

Is it possible to make a build signed with this provisoning profile with the latest Xamarin Studio and XCode 5.0.2?

I have been able to do so thus far on our standard account without logging into a developer account in the menu in Xamarin Studio->Preferences->Developer Accounts and doing the same in XCode. Is this a requirement now?

Comment: Getting the obvious questions out of the way: Did you double-click/add to keychain the certificate and profile?  They should be available after you do that.

Comment: OK, I just repro'd this on my machine. Only profiles my Apple ID is linked to show up.  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com :)

Comment: Yeah, definitely have the provisioning profile and *.p12 imported correctly. I even have the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1465) so I can view the profiles manually, it shows up as valid. I will email Xamarin support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a Xamarin Customer Support Engineer.
This is apparently a known issue in Xamarin Studio 4.2.0 and 4.2.1. This is fixed in 4.2.2 should be released very shortly. In the meantime, you can downgrade to 4.0.13 from your account downloads page.

Comment: After wasting several hours I'm glad I found this.  I'm having the same exact issue.....